# Mean of $e^{-y^2|X|^2}$, if X is a random walk with varying step size and y is normally distributed

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, expected-value, random-walk

*Problem*

Suppose a random walk in 2D with step sizes determined by $f(m) = (\frac{1}{2} + m)$, where the final position is $X = \sum_{m=0}^{N-1} x_m f(m)$ and $x_m \in \mathbb{C}$ (for example $x_m = e^{- i \phi_m}$ where $\phi_m$ is uniformly distributed over [0, $2\pi$]). What is the expectation value $\mathbb{E}[e^{-y^2|X|^2}]$, if $y\sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2)$ is normally distributed and independent of $X$?

*Attempted solution*

To first verify the behaviour of the exponentiated random walk, we assume that $y$ is constant and we set $y = \sigma$. With this, the expectation value becomes $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-\sigma^2)^k}{k!}\mathbb{E}[(|X|^2)^k] \approx \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (- \sigma^2)^k (\frac{N^3}{3} + \mathcal{O}(N))^k = \frac{1}{1 + \sigma^2 N^3/3}$. This solution has been verified with numerical simulations, by random sampling the result of the random walk and calculating the mean of the exponentiated distance.

To consider the original problem, we must calculate the mean $\mathbb{E}[ \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(y^2)^k}{k!}(-|X|^2)^k] = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{\mathbb{E}[(y^2)^k]}{k!}\mathbb{E}[(-|X|^2)^k]$. Here, we can use the fact that $\mathbb{E}[y^{2k}] = \sigma^{2k} (2k-1)!!$. With this, and with the approximation $\mathbb{E}[(-|X|^2)^k] = k! (N^3/3)^k$, the mean becomes $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (2k-1)!! (\sigma^2 N^3/3)^k$. This final expression however does not converge. From numerical simulations, we verify that the mean does converge.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more what you mean by the $f$ and the step sizes? What is $N$? Is it random? Is it independent of the $x_m$?

Comment: @MushuNrek, here $N$ is a constant, and represents the number of steps taken by the random walk. It is independent, and I am trying to express the expectation value as a function of $N$. $f(m)$ is the length of the random walk at the $m^{th}$ step. So each $m^{th}$ step of the random walk has a growing length determined by $(1/2 + m)$

Comment: I have some more questions: 1) where do you get your first approximation from? 2) If I am not mistaken, $\exp(-y^2\vert X\vert^2) \leq 1$ so that the expectation necessarily is bounded by 1 and thus finite. Then, how is it possible that the mean does not converge?